# grab logo of sites using php and cURL

Tags: php, sql, curl

I want to grab logo of website using curl and php.

what i actually want is to show a input field to the user and when user will enter a url in the field the script should grab logo of that url.
i dont know how to do that.im confused :S

i there any solution? 
its not impossible because allmyfavs is using that .

Answer (score 1):

The manual method is resolving the homepage, looking for `<meta rel="shortcut icon" ...` reference, or load the default `http://example.com/favicon.ico` as fallback, then convert it and display the image.

It's much simpler if you use free existing services, like the Google favicon API:
[`http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com`](http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.stackoverflow.com)

Simply cut out the domain name, append it to the service API and you have a complete image tag:

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
print "<img src='http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=$domain'>";
```

Comment: its not showing for all sites :( its show of few sites :(  and its showing icons whereas i need full logo ,is there anyway for that?

Comment: @cute: No. If a site does not provide a favicon, then there is no way to get one automatically. -- If you are after web site scraping (which extracting a logo necessitates), then you need a more complex solution and heaps of heuristics. Since many logos are nowadays referenced via CSS, it's not really practical to do. -- You could investigate phpQuery however for scanning websites for images / and guesstimating which the logo is.

Comment: @cute: Nope. But info@allmyfaves.com can tell you. Did you investigate phpQuery yet? Something like `$dom->find("img[src*=logo]").attr("src");` might cover half the sites.

Comment: mario ,yes i tried but its much confusing,can you help? do you have something?

Comment: can you create a sample php file with code for me? link that major files? thanks in advance! it will be good if i could contact you by messenger on email!

Comment: @cute: No. If you don't know PHP then I can't help you. Stackoverflow is only for programming help, not for for-free coding. Try getafreelancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the source located on http://www.controlstyle.com/articles/programming/text/php-favicon/ . Note that it might not work in all sources where the .ico file is not inside the main page (it might, might not, you have to work it out for those cases in particular). Or you can use the Google one suggested up there.